# plupload not working in landscape for iOS

Tags: ios, plupload, multifile-uploader

I am using plupload in a website and it works on every other browser and device, but in landscape view of iPhone or iPad, the camera roll (select file functionality) does not come up at all. Any help, is this a known issue?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by adding onresize function where I refresh the uploader (plupload). This was caused by the fact that on resize, plupload recalculates the position on the transparent div overlay which triggers the opening of the select file dialog (in the case of iOS, that is the camera roll). However, that div gets replaced on a wrong position, and not over the button.

`$(window).resize(function() {
     uploader.refresh();
});`

That repositions the plupload generated div on the correct position.